# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the localhost

Tags: jquery, django, cordova

I have backend in Django and REST framework for API serving. 
I'm trying to make nativ app with cordova framework.

I built some service:

```
var RegionService = function(){
    var url;

    this.initialize = function(){
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/regions/";
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    this.List = function(){
        return $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : url
        });
    }

    this.Get = function(id){
        return $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : url + id + "/"
        });
    }

}
```

and in index.js

```
var regions = new RegionService();

regions.initialize().done(function() {
    console.log("Regions initialized");

    regions.List().done(function(data){
        console.log("LIST");
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I'm testing cordova by browser platform:
cordova run browser

And when I run this app I get in console in browser:

```
Regions initialized
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/regions/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8001' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Django backend run on 127.0.0.1:8000, and mobile app 127.0.0.1:8001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) on your django backend. Check out this django app: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

The app adds middleware that adds CORS headers on every response, so you don't have to change any of your views, or the views from the django rest framework.

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

In your settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  '127.0.0.1:8001',
)
```

While developing locally, you could also try the setting: `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to allow cross-site requests from any host. You shouldn't do that in any non-local environment though.